# issue in pheonix sql intergration with zeppelin

Tags: hbase, apache-zeppelin, apache-phoenix

I want to integrate phoenix with zeppelin, I am running Hbase on standalone PC with internal zookeeper set up i.e setting **export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true** in **hbase-env.sh** ,and I configured phoenix Server and Client jars, phoenix from command line work fine , I tested using **./sqlline.py localhost** , I can run the pheonix queries .

I need to setup pheonix interpretar in zeppelin , i followed this link 
https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.1/interpreter/jdbc.html to setup interpreter in zeppling .

Now when I run the below command in zeppelin I am getting the below error

```
%pheonix
!tables
```

getting the below error

*RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1503311785012, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: The node /hbase-unsecure is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.*

Comment: Hi, It's would be helpful if you describe what is your zeppelin version (i guess 0.6.1?) and the whole setting for hbase (jdbc interpreter).

Comment: my zeppelin version is  zeppelin-0.7.0 ..                                  default.driver org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
default.url jdbc:phoenix:localhost:2181
default.user gpadmin
zeppelin.interpreter.localRepo /home/user1/HadoopInstallations/zeppelin-0.7.0-bin-all/local-repo/2CQ4KV2C4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a little overdue answer, but it might work for others. 
It looks your default.url incomplete, try to replace it as

```
jdbc:phoenix:localhost:2181:/hbase-unsecure
```